# How to change the format of a dictionary?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, flot

In a MVC JsonResult action I bind data to a dictionary and return it through JSON. It gives me data in a different form than what I require.

My code:

```
var query = obj.Where(x => x.Date > new DateTime(01 / 01 / 2000)
                        && x.Date <= Convert.ToDateTime(shortDate))
               .GroupBy(x => x.Date)
               .Select(x => new { LogDate = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });

Dictionary<string, int> openWith =  new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var output in query)
{
   openWith.Add(output.LogDate.ToShortDateString(), output.Count);
}
string letter = "letter";
var chartsdata = openWith;
return Json(chartsdata,letter, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

---

The JSON data comes in the form:

```
var data1 = {
    "01/28/2015": 1,
    "01/30/2015": 6, 
    "01/29/2015": 1, 
    "01/22/2015": 3, 
    "01/20/2015": 1, 
    "01/10/2015": 5 }
```

To draw a graph I need the data in the form:

```
var data1 = [
    [gd(2015, 1, 28), 1],
    [gd(2015, 1, 30), 6],
    [gd(2015, 1, 29), 1],
    [gd(2015, 1, 22), 3],
    [gd(2015, 1, 20), 1],
    [gd(2015, 1, 10), 5] ]
```

Please let me know if anyone knows: how can I change the format of data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
foreach (var output in query)
{
    openWith.Add("gd(" + output.LogDate.Year + ", " +  output.LogDate.Month + ", "
    + output.LogDate.Day + ")", output.Count);
}
```

Comment: Try to use string format instead of using `+` for separating the strings.

Comment: Now the data will be `[["gd(2015, 1, 28)", 1]...]`  instead of `[[gd(2015, 1, 28), 1]...]`

Comment: Thanks for help ... but its return like : {"gd(2015, 1, 28)":1,"gd(2015, 1, 30)":6}

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
foreach (var output in query)
{
    openWith.Add(output.LogDate.Subtract(new DateTime(1970,1,1)).TotalMilliseconds, output.Count);
}
```

This way, you calculate the timestamps on serverside and you don't need to call the `gd` function.

Comment: its shows error : has some invalid argument beacuse dictionary key in string format

Comment: @sandeepsingh you have to change `openWith` to `Dictionary<double, int>` since a `double` is now used instead of a `string`

Answer (score 0):

Your returned string isn't valid JSON according to the [JSON standard](http://json.org/).  The expression `gd(2015, 1, 28)` is not one of the valid JSON primitives, which are `"string"` (in quotes), `number`, `true`, `false` and `null`.  As far as I know none of the built-in .Net JSON formatters will produce JSON that looks like that.

Thus you will need to manually construct a string containing the desired expression yourself and return it as such:

```
        var jsonString = query.Aggregate(new StringBuilder("["), (sb, pair) =>
        {
            if (sb.Length > 1)
                sb.AppendLine(",");
            return sb.AppendFormat("[gd({0}, {1}, {2}), {3}]", pair.LogDate.Year, pair.LogDate.Month, pair.LogDate.Day, pair.Count);
        }).Append("]").ToString();

        Debug.WriteLine(jsonString);
```

which produces:

```
[[gd(2015, 1, 28), 1],
[gd(2015, 1, 30), 6],
[gd(2015, 1, 29), 1],
[gd(2015, 1, 22), 3],
[gd(2015, 1, 20), 1],
[gd(2015, 1, 10), 5]]
```